# Artificial Neural Network keeps predicting the same value

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to build a neural network for a letter recognition dataset, and my neural network keeps predicting the same value regardless of what data is inputted. I've normalized all the columns of the dataset.
The network takes 16 inputs has 2 hidden layers with 26 nodes each and 26 outputs

This is how the data is being normalized

```
norm_data = np.empty((20000,16))
for i in range(0,16):
    col_t  = data[:,i]
    col_n = np.true_divide(col_t - np.min(col_t),np.max(col_t) - np.min(col_t))
    for j in range(20000):
        norm_data[j][i] = col_n[j]
```

I'm using a sigmoid activation function and this is how I'm processing the inputs

```
def forwardprop(self,inp):

    def sig(x):
        return 1/1+np.exp(-x)

    sig_v = np.vectorize(sig)

    yh1 = sig_v(np.dot(inp,self.wih1) + self.b[0])
    yh2 = sig_v(np.dot(yh1,self.wh1h2) + self.b[1])
    yo = sig_v(np.dot(yh2,self.wh2o) + self.b[2])
  
    predicted_value = np.argmax(yo) + 1
    print(predicted_value)
    return yh1,yh2,yo,predicted_value
```

I don't see anything wrong with the sigmoid function, so I'm assuming it's something with my dot product or the way that I am normalizing the data

I don't think it's a problem with the backprop of error but this is how I am doing the backprop

```
def backprop(self,exp,yh1,yh2,yo):
    expected = np.full(26,0.01)
    pred = np.full(26,0.01)
    expected[exp - 1] = 0.99
    pred[np.argmax(yo)] = 0.99

    delta_o = np.subtract(expected,pred) * expected * np.subtract(1,expected)
    delta_h2 = np.dot(delta_o,self.wh2o) * (yh2) * (1 - yh2)
    delta_h1 = np.dot(delta_h2,self.wh1h2) * (yh1) * (1 - yh1)

    return delta_o,delta_h1,delta_h2,pred
def update_weight(self,delta_o,delta_h1,delta_h2,yh1,yh2,yo):
    self.wh2o = self.wh2o - self.mu * np.dot(delta_o,yo)
    self.wh1h2 = self.wh1h2 - self.mu * np.dot(delta_h2,yh2)
    self.wih1 = self.wih1 - self.mu * np.dot(delta_h1,yh1)
```

Comment: What's the definition of `self.mu`?

Comment: self.mu is a float for the learning rate

Comment: The sigmoid is incorrect, missing parenthesis, look at how the function is evaluated, or even better, plot it.